# How can I pass props from one component to another in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So I have a button ui component, and I need to insert it in another component. I have a button type and interface, which look like this:

```
type IButton = {
    className?: string,
    onClick?: MouseEventHandler;
    children: React.ReactNode;
    props: IButton;
}

interface ButtonProps{
  props: IButton;
}
```

And Button looks like this:

```
export const Button = ({props}: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button 
    className={`btn ${props.className}`}
    onClick={props.onClick}
    >
       {props.children}
    </button>
  );
```

So I should pass props through props interface.
And in another component I use the button:

```
<Button onclick={() => console.log('error')}></Button>
```

But from here on I don't know how I should pass the props. I tried making `onClick()` function but I get an error:

> Property 'props' is missing in type '{ onclick: () => void; }' but required in type 'Pick<ButtonProps, "props">

Edit: I also have propTypes:

```
Button.propTypes = {
    onclick: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: `onclick` != `onClick`, you need to be consistent bout capitalization.

Comment: *"...but required in type '`Pick<ButtonProps, "props">`"* I don't see that type anywhere in the question. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem (ideally with code in the question, but also a link to the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) with that same code).

Comment: I think it's a typo, you destructure the parameter in the `Button` definition, so it should be `const Button = ({ onClick, className, children, props }: ButtonProps)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hi! i added proptypes in the post too, so that's everything i have in the button component

Comment: @colinD i did the destructuring, but still, when i make `onclick` function in <Button> i have the same error as i wrote in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you are after:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  className?: string;
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Button = ({ className, onClick, children }: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button className={`btn ${className}`} onClick={onClick} type="button">
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

As you see, you don't need the type `IButton`, just an interface defining the props of your component.

Using parameter destructuring is quite common when working with react, so I put it like that. You can also do

```
export const Button = (props: ButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button className={`btn ${props.className}`} onClick={props.onClick} type="button">
      {props.children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Also, note that there is a `PropsWithChildren` type in react that you can use for this case, which already contains a `children` property.
You use it like that:

```
interface ButtonProps {
  className?: string;
  onClick?: React.MouseEventHandler;
  // => no "children" property here
}

export const Button = ({
  className,
  onClick,
  children,
}: PropsWithChildren<ButtonProps> /* note PropsWithChildren here */) => {
  return (
    <button className={`btn ${className}`} onClick={onClick} type="button">
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};
```

---

One more thing: it is recommended to give every `button` a [`type` attribute](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/button-has-type.md).

Comment: thank you, it was really helpful! i had problems understanding props in typescript, but now it makes more sense xd

Answer (score -1):

Your error is here: `Button = ({props}: ButtonProps) => ...`
What you are doing is [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the *props*, which is wrong in this case.

Should be: `Button = (props: ButtonProps) => ...` (without the curty brackets).